# Copy a column content to another column by value in a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Suppose I have a pandas dataframe df as

```
UserId Destination
1       A    
1       B
1       C
2       D
2       E
```

Then i would like a dataframe

```
UserId Destination NextDestination
1       A               B
1       B               C
1       C               None
2       D               E
2       E               None
```

Hope i have made myself clear by this example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
df['NextDestination'] = df.groupby('UserId')['Destination'].shift(-1)
print (df)
   UserId Destination NextDestination
0       1           A               B
1       1           B               C
2       1           C             NaN
3       2           D               E
4       2           E             NaN
```